# Ubicación de los segmentos en ensamblador

Tags: nasm

Muy buenas a tod@s, estoy aprendiendo ensamblador en la universidad, pero hay algo que no termino de entender, es lo siguiente:

Cuando hablamos, por ejemplo, del segmento de datos ¿Este está en la misma área de memoria que la de el código? Es decir, si escribo en el segmento de datos ¿Se escribe a la vez al segmento de código? ¿O son segmentos separados?

Si mi código para un bootloader empieza en `0x7c00`, ¿CS y DS empiezan en la misma dirección? ¿O deben obligatoriamente empezar en áreas distintas?

No termino de entender bien la ubicación de cada segmento.

Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Los segments en assembler indican como armar el archivo objectfile y dan pautas de cómo luego el loader (bios, sistema operativo, etc..) asigna los espacios de memoria.
por lo general la convención es

**.data** son variables estáticas con valores iniciales, se marca como zona de lectura/escritura.

**.text** es código ejecutable y se marca como de sólo lectura (aunque depende del loader y la arquitectura/procesador si es realmente sólo lectura).

**.bss** (block starting symbol) son variables y constantes que no tienen valores iniciales, típicamente se rellena con ceros, no suele incluirse en el archivo objectfile, salvo el largo del espacio que ocupa, se marca como de lectura/escritura.

En el caso de un bootloader el archivo objectfile va a ser cargado por el bios (loader) y debe caber en 512 bytes pues en x86 PC la secuencia de arranque es la siguiente:

1) el procesador se enciende y busca el BIOS en la dirección 0xFFFFFFF0.

2) el BIOS hace un par de cosas y luego busca un sector de arranque en los dispositivos de almacenamiento que identifica.

3) típico sector de arranque son 512 bytes al principio del disco y terminan con los byte 0x55 y 0xAA (firma de arranque).

4) si se cumple todo eso, elige el medio(disco) con la mas alta prioridad y carga esos 512 bytes en la dirección 0x007C00.

5) devuelve el control de ejecución al cpu a partir de esa dirección efectivamente ejecutando el bootloader.

Por lo tanto `DS` y `CS` van a tener el mismo valor en un bootloader pues apuntan al mismo segmento/pagina de memoria (64k en x86) mas que suficiente para un programejo que debe tener 512 bytes máximo.

Dicho de otra manera los "datos" van a estar en las direcciones `DS:SI` mientras que el código se ejecutará en las direcciones `CS:IP`. Mismo segmento de memoria, diferente offset (source index/instruction pointer)

https://wiki.osdev.org/Segmentation

https://www.reinterpretcast.com/creating-a-bare-bones-bootloader

https://arjunsreedharan.org/post/82710718100/kernel-101-lets-write-a-kernel

http://joebergeron.io/posts/post_two.html